# Paypal Payment Received, Execute SQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I would like to know if it's possible to execute a SQL Query on receipt of a PayPal Donation.

The Process would be as follows:

- User Donates to PayPal account.
- SQL Insert/Update awards points to the Donator.

Just like in some MMORPG's. You Pay to get points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible you can setup a PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN).
This will allow you to run a script for every payment received. [See Here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).

Here is the [PayPal API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) and Here are the [PayPal C# Samples.](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-dotnet)

To install the C# SDK as a dependency in your project, please run the following nuget command.

```
nuget install PayPalRestApiSDK
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a form to set up a payment on PayPal something like this...

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> 
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your@email-registered-with-paypal.com">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://yourdomain.com/notifypage.aspx">
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="{username or similar}">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">  
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">  
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.00">  
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">  
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
</form>
```

On a successful payment, the notify_url is called from the PayPal server and information is posted back, including the invoice number you specified in the form.

In notifypage.aspx in the Page_Load() method, you need to verifiy that the post came from PayPal, then read the posted form variables and update your database accordingly, using the invoice value to match the payment to the user in your database. Something like..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Post back to either sandbox or live
    string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

    //Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
    string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
    strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

    //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(),                         System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    streamOut.Write(strRequest);
    streamOut.Close();
    StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
    streamIn.Close();

    if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
    {
    //check the payment_status is Completed
    //check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    var userName = Request["invoice"];
    //update database
    }
    else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
    {
    //log for manual investigation
    }
    else
    {
    //log response/ipn data for manual investigation
    }
}
```

}

The form values posted back are listed at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

and more information can be found at https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-info-outside